# Performance difference map() vs withColumn()

Tags: performance, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have a table with over 100 columns. I need to remove double quotes from certain columns. I found 2 ways to do it, using withColumn() and map()

Using withColumn()

```
cols_to_fix = ["col1", ..., "col20"]
for col in cols_to_fix:
    df = df.withColumn(col, regexp_replace(df[col], "\"", ""))
```

Using map()

```
def remove_quotes(row: Row) -> Row:
    row_as_dict = row.asDict()
    cols_to_fix = ["col1", ..., "col20"]
    for column in cols_to_fix:
        if row_as_dict[column]:
            row_as_dict[column] = re.sub("\"", "", str(row_as_dict[column]))
    return Row(**row_as_dict)
 
df = df.rdd.map(remove_quotes).toDF(df.schema)
```

Here is my question. I found using map() takes about 4 times longer than withColumn() on a table that has ~25M records. I will really appreciate if any fellow stack overflow user can explain the reason for the performance difference, so that I can avoid similar pitfall in future.

Comment: You can start here: [spark dataframe conversion to rdd takes a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906387/spark-dataframe-conversion-to-rdd-takes-a-long-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, one piece of advice: do not convert DataFrame to RDD and just do `df.map(your function here)`, this may save a lot of time.
the following page
https://dzone.com/articles/apache-spark-3-reasons-why-you-should-not-use-rdds
would save us a lot of time, its main conclusion is that RDD is remarkably slow than DataFrame/Dataset, not to mention the time used for the conversion from DataFrame to RDD.

Let's talk about map and withColumn without any conversion between DataFrame to RDD now.

Conclusion first: map is usually 5x slower than withColumn. the reason is that map operation always involves deserialization and serialization while withColumn can operate on column of interest.
to be specific, map operation should deserialize the Row into several parts on which the operation will be carrying,

An example here :
assume we have a DataFrame which looks like

```
+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|    Java|      20000|
|  Python|     100000|
|   Scala|       3000|
+--------+-----------+
```

Then we want to increment all the values in column users_count by 1, we can do it like this:

```
df.map(row => {
  val usersCount = row.getInt(1) + 1
  (row.getString(0), usersCount)
}).toDF("language", "users_count_incremented_by_1")
```

In the code above, we firstly need to deserialize every row to extract the values in the 2nd column, after that we output the modified values and save it as an DataFrame(this step requires serialization of (a,b) into Row(a, b) since DataFrame is nothing but a DataSet of Rows).
for more detailed explanation, check the following excellent article
https://medium.com/@fqaiser94/udfs-vs-map-vs-custom-spark-native-functions-91ab2c154b44

`map` can not operate on the column itself but have to operate on the values of the column, getting the values require deserialization, saving it as a `DataFrame` requires serialization.

But map is still of great use: with the help of map method people could implement very sophisticated operations while just built-in operations could be done if we just use `withColumn`.

To sum it up, map is slower but more flexible, `withColumn` is surely the most efficient while it's functionality is limited.